# ArrayStoreException in React Native Android app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, sentry

I am getting the following fatal error in production on my React Native Android app:

[image]

It occurs on Android 8.0.1. Below is the breadcrumbs from the Sentry stack trace:

[image]

It does not occur on any of the test devices / emulators I have, only on random other Android devices. Any help and/or advice on how to debug it would also be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you're not uploading the proguard files, so the function names are minified. It'll be easier to troubleshoot if you get the right function names: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/proguard/